# Trying to add My User Name for read permission in registry, I tried with source code , it is not adding my user into registry->permission

Tags: vb.net, windows-10, registrykey

Trying to add read permission to the User in pragmatically, Am not getting error, But not added into the registry

```
    Dim Keyss = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.Users
    try
    For Each a In Keyss.GetSubKeyNames
            Dim key = Keyss.OpenSubKey(a)
    Next 
    '    key = Keyss.OpenSubKey("S-1-5-20")
    Catch ex As SecurityException
        'Dim rs = Keyss.GetAccessControl()
        Dim rs As New RegistrySecurity()
        'Dim currentUserStr = Environment.UserDomainName + "\" + Environment.UserName
        Dim currentUserStr = Environment.UserName
        Try
            rs.AddAccessRule(New RegistryAccessRule(currentUserStr, RegistryRights.ReadKey, AccessControlType.Allow))
        Catch exw As Exception
              MsgBox(exw.ToString)
        End Try
    End Try
```

Comment: Try to debug your code row by row.

Comment: Also show the error message. Your inner `Catch` is empty so you can't get an error.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have added, still am not getting any errors in exceptions black.

Comment: Not applicable to your issues, but I believe keys implement `IDisposable` and thus should be either disposed manually or enclosed in `Using` blocks.